# Deja Dup Stuck at Preparing

Tags: backup, 17.10, deja-dup

I need to restore a Backup via Deja Dup, but it is stuck. The Backups are on an remote server and are connected via sftp and are selectable at an earlier Point in the Restore Menu with correct timestamps. 
I am currently using Ubuntu 17.10

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PTFIJ.png)
Thank you a lot,
David

Comment: How long have you waited? It can take a really long time.  BTW, your screenshot adds no useful information.  I, too, wish deja-dup was a little - well, a lot - less opaque about what it's doing.  I look at the traffic between my pc and the server to see if it's actually doing anything.

Comment: It seems I am having the same issue. There is a [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/duplicity/+bug/1778638) I have filled for it.